# Update Firestore Structure

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a structure in the Firestore where I have to make an update in Swift.
This is my structure:

```
Customer
        userId
            subscription
                    documentID
                            items[]  ->  (items is an Array)
                                [ 0 ]
                                    price ->  (dictionary)
                                        product ->  (dictionary)
                                            metadata ->  (dictionary  
                                                data: “string” (this data update)
```

Please, can anyone help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CoKt.png)

Comment: What does 'make an update' mean exactly? What are you attempting to update? Do you have some code you've attempted? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your data structure follows a collection>document>collection hierarchy. If that is the case you can use the setData feature to update the dictionary.

Here is a sample code snippet that may start you off in the right direction:

```swift
func updateData(newData: String, documentID: String) {
    
    let object : [String: String] = ["data" : newData]
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
    
    db.collection("Customer").document(userID).collection("subscription")
        .document(documentID).collection("items").document("price").collection("product")
        .document("metadata").setData(object, merge: false) { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("There was an error updating the childArray: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Updating childArray was successful")
            }
        }
}
```

You may also want to review the firebase documentation regarding updating elements in an array: [Firestore: Update elements in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

Comment: Hi Marmaduk, thank you for answered. "items" is an Array and "price" is in position [0].

Comment: @LinoP. Please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer if it helped you.

Comment: I sorry, unfortunately it didn't help me

Comment: @LinoP read the link in my answer regarding arrays.